# Does PFInstallation.currentInstallation().channels changes affects globally?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

This is probably a silly question but I wanted to be sure that changing `PFInstallation.currentInstallation().channels` I'm only affecting current device subscriptions and not global channels.

I basically wanted to be validate that doing this

```
PFInstallation.currentInstallation().channels = []
```

I'm not deleting all channels from entire application. I currenlty have a single device so can't test it myself.

Comment: @Downvoter: what's wrong with the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, this is changing only the channels on the installation for the current device.

Comment: Great, I was trying to build a custom push audience on the dashboard and when I executed `PFInstallation.currentInstallation().channels = []` all channels disappeared from autocomplete textbox. I freaked out thinking this could delete channels globally

Comment: Well, if you only have 1 device then it kinda is, but it will only impact the one device